# Inserting Values in Hidden Form Fields with Dynamic Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I'm trying to insert value based on a button click into a hidden field.

I'm using id's which are all unique. However, the data does not seem to be submitting in the `POST` request.

I'm using unique ids as there are multiple forms.

What's wrong with what I'm doing and how can I fix it?

```js
function buttonClick(theButton){
        document.getElementById('clicked_button4562').value = theButton.value;
        alert(theButton.value)
        return true;
    }
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="button_action" id="clicked_button4562" value=""/>

<button class="button is-primary is-outlined next" name="button_action" type="submit" value="tweet" onclick="return buttonClick(this)">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Tweet</span>
</button>
<button class="button is-info is-outlined next" name="button_action" type="submit" onclick="return buttonClick(this)" data-button_action="save" value="save">
  <span class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
  </span>
  <span>Save</span>
</button>
```

Update:
Added code for POST request as requested:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            for (var i = 0, form; form = document.forms[i]; ++i) {//iterate throu forms
                initForm(form);
            }
        });
        function initForm(frm) {
            //find elements of interest inside the form
            var fileUpload = frm.file1;//get by 'name' attribute inside the form
            var statusInfo = frm.querySelector('.status');
            var progressBar = frm.querySelector('.progress');
            var progressInfo = frm.querySelector('.loaded_n_total');

            //update. 'textarea' is in a separate form which doesn't contain 'file1'
            if (fileUpload)
               fileUpload.addEventListener('change', uploadFile);

            function uploadFile(e) {//'e' is 'change' event. It isn't used and may be ommited
                var file = this.files[0];// 'this' is fileUpload element
                //alert(file.name + " | " + file.size + " | " + file.type);
                console.log(file);
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("file1", file, file.name);

                //update. A form with fileUpload contains other elements
                for (var i = 0, el; el = this.form.elements[i]; ++i) {
                    if (el !== this)
                        formdata.append(el.name, el.value);
                }

                statusInfo.innerHTML = 'prepare upload';
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var uploadValue = this.getAttribute("data-uploadValue");
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "/upload/" + uploadValue); //
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
            function progressHandler(event) {
                progressInfo.innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                progressBar.value = Math.round(percent);
                statusInfo.innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
            }

            function completeHandler(event) {
                statusInfo.innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
                progressBar.value = 0; //wil clear progress bar after successful upload
            }

            function errorHandler(event) {
                statusInfo.innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            }

            function abortHandler(event) {
                statusInfo.innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            }
        }//initForm

    </script>
```

Comment: inspecting the input element, the value of the button does get assigned to it.  could you add the code for the post request?

Comment: added the code as requested

Comment: @DannyMcwaves The value gets assigned in the SO snippet but when I copy it over and run the code locally, it doesn't work, throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: seems to work with only one but when there are multiple with different ids, it doesn't

Comment: @Adders, all the buttons and inputs have their own separate forms, right?

Comment: Yea that's right

Comment: @Adders have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you remove the `{` and `}` characters, your code will work (strangely, it will still work even if there is a `]` or a `[`). 
See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) MDN page.

> Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

I don't know what you are trying to do but I would stay away from abnormal IDs.

Comment: The `{{item[0]}}` is just a int variable so it would actually look like clicked_button2546

Comment: @Adders But the value is still just that in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById( "hiddenInput" );

function proccessButtonClick( evt ) {

 var btn = evt.target;
 hiddenInput.value = btn.value;
    
    for ( v in btn.dataset ) {
     hiddenInput.value += "|" + btn.dataset[v];
    }
    
}

function showHiddenInputValue( evt ) {
 alert( hiddenInput.value );
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput"/>
<button value="tweet" data-v1="tweet1" data-v2="tweet2" onclick="proccessButtonClick(event)">Tweet</button>
<button value="foo" data-v1="foo1" data-v2="foo2" onclick="proccessButtonClick(event)">Foo</button>
<button value="bar" data-v1="bar1" data-v2="bar2" onclick="proccessButtonClick(event)">Bar</button>
<button onclick="showHiddenInputValue(event)">Show hidden input value!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This won't work with multiple forms though, will it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function buttonClick(theButton){
        document.getElementById('clicked_button4562').value = theButton.value;
        alert(theButton.value)
        return false;
    }
```

the buttons in the form are submit buttons and when you click on it, it changes the value of the input but it also submits the form, thereby setting the form to it's original state. you need to prevent default by returning false from the click handler.